# Como puedo actualizar un atributo de mi objeto que es un useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Esto es mi useState inicial que se llena con una petición.

```
//Esto es mi estado inicial que se llena con una petición.
const [datos, setDatos] = useState(
        {
            stbPersona_ID: 0,
            sasstTipoServicioInformatico_ID: 0,
            sasstProductoInformatica_ID: 0,
            observacion: '',
            sasstEstadoDocumento_ID: 5,
            sasstTipoDocumento_ID: 0,
            creadoPor: 0,
            fechaCreacion: Date(),
            actualizadoPor: 0,
            fechaActualizacion: Date(),
            isServicioSistema: false,
            isAutorizacion: false,
            isFormularioPermiso: false,
            isCambioDatos: false,
            numeroDocumento: 0,
            sasstSolicitud_ID: 0


        }
    )
```

> al relizar un cambio en un select se guardan en la variable correpondiente

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setDatos({
            ...datos,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
        refreshServices()

    }
```

> pero ese producto nuevo seleccionado puede que ocupe Autorizacion , CambiodeDatos , oh es Formulario y debo actualizar esos campos sin perder los anteriores.

```
const refreshServices = () => {
       if (datos.sasstProductoInformatica_ID !== null || datos.sasstProductoInformatica_ID > 0) {
           let data = services.find(x => x.sasstProductoInformatica_ID === parseInt(datos.sasstProductoInformatica_ID))
           setDatos({
               ...datos,
               isAutorizacion: data.isAutorizacion,
               isCambioDatos: data.isCambioDatos,
               isFormularioPermiso: data.isFormularioPermiso
           })
         
       }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema estás teniendo?

Comment: no se como actualizar solo ciertos atributos de un objeto que es un useState sin peder la info de los atributos anteriores